# git log to list only merged changes from gerrit

Tags: git, logging, version-control, gerrit, history

Not sure if it's bug, but running git log on particular branch lists down even non-approved changes.

Scenario:

Changes committed & pushed for review in Gerrit with below

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev_branch
```

Review is not yet done & is not merged to central repo image of dev_branch and is still appearing in 'open' changes in dashboard.

Running `git log dev_branch` enlists list *hash* of last committed files on local branch as well (  which is not approved & which has not made it's way to central repo).

Is there a filter by which we can restrict to get git log on only merged ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dev_branch` is a local branch that includes unreviewed commits. If you'd like to see the history of the branch `dev_branch` in the server side repository, which does not include those commits yet:

```
git fetch origin dev_branch
git log origin/dev_branch
```

In case `dev_branch` does not have an upstream `origin/dev_branch` for some reason, the following commands work in a more reliable way:

```
git fetch origin dev_branch
git log FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!. Accepting this. In learning phase - but answers like above will ease things which I am looking to do on simple strategy of defining needy release process :)